# Wicd does not like to reconnect upon resuming in the same or different location

Tags: wireless, networking, suspend, wicd

```
Ubuntu 13.10 - Samsung Series 9 - Wireless connection only
```

Issue: Wicd does not automatically re-connect after the laptop is suspended. This happens when the laptop is turned back on in the same room, or when I get back home and open it up. I have the "automatically connect to this network" on all of my preferred networks in each location. Additionally, when I resume in another location, the wireless network list does not refresh.

I have network manager and all of its parts uninstalled. Wicd is the only wireless connection software that I am running.

I have looked all over Ask Ubuntu, but none of the solutions (installing, purging, pillaging) have not solved this.

Answer (score 3):

The [wicd-daemon package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/wicd-daemon/filelist) should add a hook for pm-utils to handle this with the file:

> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd

I'm pretty sure pm-utils gets pulled in by default as part of ubuntu-desktop (via some other things) but if you removed network-manager and/or other gnome parts then perhaps you lost it somewhere along the way. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install pm-utils
```

Otherwise, I think you will have to start looking for errors in the log files, starting with:

> /var/log/pm-suspend.log

Comment: Ok - I see the 55wicd file, and my pm-utils is on the last version. What exactly am I looking for in the pm-suspend.log?

Comment: @Zlatty: The log file records which scripts it runs when the suspend happens, and the result they return. So you want to check firstly that the 55wicd script is being called at all. Second is any mention of errors or failure response, either for 55wicd specifically, or any other script.

Comment: I just ran through the pm-suspend.log and the only thing I saw regarding 55wicd is the following:: 

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd resume suspend: success.

Each time there is a success at the end of it, so I assume that's working?